# Angular mat menu position

Tags: angular

Hi i would like to have a mat-menu open to the left.

i got some scratch code in stackblitz, here is the link

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-menu-position-aside-6ab669?file=src/app/menu-overview-example.html

the structure should like this
Menu -> Item 1 Item 2 Item 3

or the oppposite direction
Item 1 Item 2 Item 3 <- Menu

any ideas? thanks

Comment: Question not clear. What is the issue? Is see it opens already to the left.

Comment: hi..what i want is..after i click menu...item 1 item 2 item 3 open directly. right now is after i click menu..hover mouse in Item 1 and then Item 2 show. i dont want it like that.

Answer (score 0):

The `matMenuTrigger` exposes an `openMenu()` function that can be called to open the menu programmatically.

[stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-menu-open-sub-menu-automatically)

So to achieve the desired effect:

1. listen to the `menuOpened` event of the main trigger,
2. when main trigger opens, call `openMenu()` on the sub-trigger.

The only issue is, that since the sub-trigger will open before the parent has finished animating, it will not position properly. So:

3. use the `setTimeout` function to delay the opening of the sub-trigger.

Comment: hi...thank you for your suggestion but how i change the position for Item 1 and Item 2 directly on the right side from Menu. right now Item 1 and 2 is little bit below the Menu.